# How to downgrade magento 2.x EE to CE?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise-2

I need to migrate my **magento 2 EE to CE**. I have found many posts regarding this but all of them are of Magento 1. Can anyone please suggest how to do this for Magento 2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not provide downgrade like EE to CE. Support only

**- EE to EE**

**- CE to EE**

**- CE to CE**

Answer (score 0):

First step is to change the package requirement in the composer.json, then after the composer update, you will facing the real issue: the database structure..
(this post should help you: https://blog.magepsycho.com/migrate-downgrade-magento-2-from-enterprise-to-community-edition/)

So I've started to work on SQL script to convert EE schema to CE schema.

Feel free to contribute but it's already a good start: https://github.com/thomas-kl1/magento2-downgrade-ee-ce

There is also this tool:
https://github.com/hoangnm89/m2-query-ee-to-ce/blob/master/db-ee-to-ce.sql
which just fix the schema without removing the extra tables.